# Why doesn't Bean know about his final son?

Tags: enders-game

We know that Ender found Bean's last child still alive on Ganges, so:

1. Why did Petra not send mail to Bean?

   - Surely, she knows that he's still alive (just few months with him since he left).
   - Why not tell him about that?
2. Before the ship carrying Arkanian Delphiki and his surrogate mother takes off, Graff knows about the boy

   - he has done the check (opening Chapter 12 Ender in Exile), and yet he left everything for Ender to solve, he didn't even send a note to Bean to tell him that his last child was found.
   - And even later when he has information from Val about everything that happened, he still doesn't send anything to Bean (maybe he can't pay the fee?).

Comment: Is there a clear book indication that Graff knew that Randall Firth had the key turned on before Valentine's report of what happened to Ender?

Comment: @DVK yes, Graff know about that (like i said above he has done the check), but does that mean he cant just inform Bean his last child was found (just tell him his child was found but has gone with one of the colony ship and nothing else about the child's condition)? It will change nothing about the storyline except make it a bit longer but it will make someone like me satisfied. Or just me think about this LOL?

Comment: I'll need to check the text. I am unsure that Bean was easily contact-able at that time. Good catch, either way!